# EF Read/Write keyless table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a table that does not have keys, having Id as the only non-nullable column, I have to write to it so I have to define keys on my code, selecting columns that might work as keys.

```
[Table("AvailableProducts")]
public class AvailableProducts
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? A { get; set; }
public string? B { get; set; }
public string? C { get; set; }
}
```

Columns Id, A and B all can be combination keys.

Setting on my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableProducts>().HasKey(u => new
{
u.Id,
u.A,
u.B
});
```

No problem calling **context.SaveChanges();** Data gets inserted in my table.

The problem is when trying to read data. Calling **context.ToListAsyc();**

I'm getting as error:
***Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.***

If I set **modelBuilder.Entity().HasNoKey();** I don't get the error and get the data I need, but I can't no longer save data, 'cause EF does need keys to write.

I've tried changing the properties to **[Key]**, **[Required]** and changing from **string?** to **string** but nothing seems to work, I can either save or read but never both.

Comment: I tested your code that this code is okay (example: AvailableProducts _d = new AvailableProducts();
_d .A = "a";  _d .B = "aaa";   _d .Id = 3; _d .C = "ss";
db.AvailableProducts.Add(availableProducts);db.SaveChanges();
      var _results =  db.AvailableProducts.ToListAsync();),

can you share insert code and more code